# Typeerror: unhashable type list in CNN

Tags: python, typeerror, conv-neural-network

everybody, I'm running a convolutional neural network and the next line of code

```
    nsmilesd = {}
for key in smiles_dict.keys():
    nsmilesd[key] = list[set(smiles_dict[key])- set(rm)]
    print(key+ '__________NEW_len='+str(len(nsmilesd[key])))
    print(key+ '__________OLD_len='+str(len(set(smiles_dict[key]))))
```

shows me the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-c3bfc0dab9dc> in <module>
      1 nsmilesd = {}
      2 for key in smiles_dict.keys():
----> 3     nsmilesd[key] = list[set(smiles_dict[key])- set(rm)]
      4     print(key+ '__________NEW_len='+str(len(nsmilesd[key])))
      5     print(key+ '__________OLD_len='+str(len(set(smiles_dict[key]))))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do you mean to use `list(...)` with normal parentheses instead of square brackets `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `list[...]` to `list(...)` on line 3.
i.e.
`nsmilesd[key] = list[set(smiles_dict[key])- set(rm)]`
to
`nsmilesd[key] = list(set(smiles_dict[key])- set(rm))`

Comment: Hi, the same problem persists, I made those changes.   ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-16fd48785daf> in <module>
      1 nsmilesd = {}
      2 for key in smiles_dict.keys():
----> 3     nsmilesd[key] = list(set(smiles_dict[key])- set(rm))
      4     print(key+ '__________NEW_len='+str(len(nsmilesd[key])))
      5     print(key+ '__________OLD_len='+str(len(set(smiles_dict[key]))))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' ```